# Buildfarm pull request test fails without its reason indicated

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A [pull request test](http://build.ros.org/job/Lpr__ar_track_alvar__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/12/consoleFull) (for [this PR](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/pull/39)) keeps failing on buildfarm. Looking at its full log I can't find the reason -- tests seem to be passing. I appreciate if someone could take a look at the full log and spot the cause of the error (once this question is resolved I'll update the question title to describe better).

One thing I have no idea is the section at the very end of the job, [15. Clean up to save disk space on slaves](http://build.ros.org/job/Lpr__ar_track_alvar__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/12/consoleFull#console-section-18) where some errors are recorded that look like from Jenkins.

```
16:00:01 [xUnit] [ERROR] - Conversion error Error to convert - A file not found
16:00:01 ERROR: Step ‘Publish xUnit test result report’ aborted due to exception: 
16:00:01 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262869/buildfarm-pull-request-test-fails-without-its-reason-indicated/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2017-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears to have crashed while trying to parse the xunit test results. From the error they're likely truncated at line 2.

I browsed the workspace and found:

[image: image description]

It appears that those 39B files looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Which is not valid xunit. Possibly those unit tests are crashing before they finish writing the output?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-06-14**:
Sounds like you're right. I found there are errors happening while testcase still moved on despite them ([tracking here](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/issues/40)).